# KIll SQL Server SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `SELECT` statement which is hanging and I would like to kill it. I am accessing the server through a SQL GUI if that matters (not microsoft's).

Is there a command I can execute to kill that process?

I get this when using `EXEC('Kill ' + Pid):`

> KILL command cannot be used inside user transactions.

Comment: When you have a "hanging" statement you have a unique opportunity to study it and learn the root cause and learn more about SQL Server. So maybe learn more about `sp_who2` before you learn more about `kill`

Answer (score 3):

You could try the [`KILL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) command.

Comment: Does your GUI wrap all your statements inside an explicit transaction? Maybe try `ROLLBACK; KILL`

Comment: @Porcupine - that sentence was added to the question after my answer was posted!

Comment: Yes, likely the UI gets in the way here via being "smart" (i.e. having an implicit transaction). Need to break out of that. Or use another UI or a command line tool to submit the command.

Comment: @Barry, I know it was- I was quoting from my GUI, then I decided to add it to my post....

Answer (score 0):

If KILL command alone does not work, like you constantly get "*KILL command cannot be used inside user transactions.*" errors, then take your database `OFFLINE` and `BACKONLINE` again. This will force a full disconnect of any lingering processes on your database.

Do not do DEATTACH, as that is "overkill" and could jeapordise bringing your database back online.

If it's a production database, obviously **think** before you do this!