# Run SQL 'Kill' from Python

Tags: python, sql-server

I always retrieve data from SQL database on Python via pymssql, which may lead too many idle connections. Therefore, I write a SQL procedure to kill idle connections, and it works when I execute on SSMS. However, when I try to execute it on python it fails and raises :

> (6115, b'KILL command cannot be used inside user transactions.DB-Lib
>   error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check
>   messages from the SQL Server\n')

The following code is the method to execute SQL procedure from python,

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(server, username, password, dbname)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("exec killconn")
```

How can I deal with this?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Here is a case I found, but I am still confused how to deal with it. http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/kill-not-inside-user-transaction/

Comment: Shot in dark (likey misses) Wouldn't that be an escalation of privileges by the connection object so not allowed? or are you using the same username/password in both places?

Comment: You could create a job on SQL Server to run every 30 minutes or so and handle this for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847561/kill-sql-server-select-statement same question no answer.

Comment: Why is your program not closing & destroying its connections? Fix the root cause, not the symptom.

Comment: @scsimon yes, it is a way. Thank you.

Comment: @xQbert Okay, ╮(╯_╰)╭, thank you.

Comment: @alroc At first, I am looking for close the connection when program finish. However, the slowest part is establishing connections. So if my group of programs doesn't close the connection, they don't need to reconnect it. Thank you.

Comment: From what it looks like, `killconn` is a stored procedure and should be called using the [`callproc`](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html#calling-stored-procedures) method.

Comment: Do you want to kill it all or just specific connections?

Comment: What @alroc said. Fix the poor code by closing and disposing of your connection objects and the problem will no longer bother you.

Comment: @Sami the actual procedure will accept arguments, like hostname, idle hour.... That's already done, and it works in SSMS. Thank you.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, I am trying. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the solution to underlying issue of idle connections, but the error from SQL server is caused by pymssql wrapping each connection in a transaction by default. Commands such as KILL cannot be run inside a transaction, so fail if called this way.

To prevent pymssql, or other python database connections, from adding this transaction, *autocommit* can be set to True.

As it is a stored procedure being called, `callproc()` may be more appropriate than `execute()`.

```python
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(server, username, password, dbname)

conn.autocommit(True)

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.callproc("killconn")
```